# Having Issue on Continuous Looping on an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why the the loop stops on 3rd element and not get back the first item again?

```js
var appTxt = $('.smart-txt').hide(),
    news = ['News 1', 'News 2', 'News3'],
    count = 0;

function changeNews() {
    appTxt.fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000, function() {
        changeNews();
    }).text(news[count++]);
}
changeNews();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="smart-txt"> </h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to rewrite your logic like below,

```
function changeNews() {
    appTxt.fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000, function() {
        changeNews();
    }).text(news[count++ % news.length]);
}
```

when the `count` becomes greater than the length of `array` length, then it will return `undefined`. So `.text(undefined)` will act as a `getter` not a `setter`. That is why you are seeing the final text again and again.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o9ows1j7/)

Comment: its better to store lenght rather calculating every time.  `var intNewsLength = news.length;`

Comment: How?Will you explain it please :)

Answer (score 1):

**Change made**

```
if(count == news.length ){
  count = 0;
}
```

> Added the above condition just to initialize the count variable if it reaches the last element.

**Working Demo**

```js
var appTxt = $('.smart-txt').hide(),
    news = ['News 1', 'News 2', 'News3'],
    count = 0;

function changeNews() {
    appTxt.fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000, function() {
        changeNews();
    }).text(news[count++]);
    if(count == news.length ){
      count=0
    }
}
changeNews();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="smart-txt"> </h1>
```